# Access control from other form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a vb.net project in VS 2012 that has multiple forms. I have, lets say, Form1 with a ListView and I call a From2 from Form1. I add this code to the Load event of Form2:

```
Form1.ListViewTest.Items.Add("test")
```

The visual studio throws no errors but in fact nothing happens in the ListView control in Form1. I tried to change Modifiers from Friend to public with no success. Is there something else that I miss?

Comment: You must provide a reference to the `ListView` in `Form1`, otherwise you cannot access it. Use the constructor of `Form2` to pass the reference.
Additionally you might have a threading issue, as you are probably not allowed to access `Form1` from `Form2`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to provide a reference to the ListView in Form1 and how to use the constructor of Form2 to passs the reference?

Comment: Post your code and then we can tell you how to change it to make it work.

Comment: @user2373081 my VB.NET sucks, just pass the ListView as an Argument in your constructor of Form2

Comment: There is a form frmConnection with a tab control and a ListView named Connections in the fist tab. In the second tab there is a button with this code: Dim newform As New frmMain  'there is already a form frmMain
            newform.txtPort.Text = TextBox1.Text
            newform.Show() 'In order to load and start listening
            newform.Hide()   So a second form runs in the background and starts listening. When a client connects to this server this form shows up with Me.Show() and also I want it to add item "Client connected" on the ListView control Connections in frmConnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the instance of form1, not the form 1 object itself. Step through all open forms, and get the one you want. I personally use the .Tag object of a form, and just add a string in there to identify it.

```
    For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms

        If Not f.InvokeRequired Then
            ' Can access the form directly.
            'Get main form , use main form
            If f.Tag = "main" Then
                Dim fcast As New form_form1 '<< whatever your form name
                fcast = f
                Dim xitem As New ListViewItem
                xitem.Text = "blah"
                xitem.SubItems.Add("sub blah")

                fcast.listview1.Items.Add(xitem) '<< use listview name
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Note: The `f.InvokeRequired` check is usually only required if you run the code above within a different thread context - which is not the case here: Both forms are in the same (UI) thread. And if it is required in a multi-threaded environment, you need to provide something in the `else` branch (i.e. `BeginInvoke`), otherwise the code does nothing.

Comment: Hi, yeah. True. The code I copied this from was used in my multi threaded app at a stage. Good spot.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple, if you going to reference any control from a dialog window, there are two ways to do this, the first one is below:

Part I

1 - you make sure that the control that you want to want to access the modifier is set to Public

2 - then in the dialog window, you do this:

Dim f as Form1 ' you do not need to use new, because you don't want to use another new fresh version, you want to use the existing one, so you only use the form name as a reference

3 - you do this:

f = Ctype(Me.Owner, Form1) ' you do not need to cycle Through the form collection, because every form name is unique

f.LightGridControl.Text = "This information"

Part II

You can create a private vairiable in the declaration section of the the main window

Private _mainWin as form1 ' this is the same window unique name

then you create a

Public Property MainForm as Form1
   Get
       Return _mainWin
   End Get
   Set (ByRef value as Form1)
        _mainForm = value
   End Set
 End if

in the Button Click Event, you can write this:

Dim f as New Form2

_mainForm = Me

f.DialogBox(Me)

Then in any event from form2 that you want to access the control from form1 (MainWindow), you just do this:

Dim f as form1

f.MainForm.TextBox1.Text = "My Information"

It is that easy my friend!! Good Luck, let me know how did it go.

Have a Nice Day!! Hope this can help somebody!!