# How to access user controls' text box from a form?

Tags: vb.net, listview, user-controls

```
Public Sub patientListView_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles patientListView.MouseClick
    patientID = patientListView.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text
    frmMain.Label1.Text = patientID.ToString
    frmBillingManagement.lblTry.Text = patientID.ToString

End Sub
```

Note: frmBillingManagement is a user control

Those code are from frmBillingPatient..

my problem is when I select a row in patientListView i cant put it into the lblTry in frmBillingManagement, its not working. But its working with the frmMain which is a form.

Comment: Please define 'Not working'.  Does it throw an error? Have you tried `.Refresh()` on the label or whole user control?

Comment: there's no error, but its not working since it doesnt change the txt of lblTry.

i already tried that .Refresh both label and user control

Comment: Are you sure `patientListView_MouseClick` is even called when you click it? Maybe add a console write debug line or something.

Comment: yes, its called because label1 changed text .. its just that lblTry doesnt.

Comment: Check our this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081978/access-control-from-other-form-vb-net) for a similar issue.

Comment: @OSKM im using user control, my code works on a form but not on a user control. :)

Comment: Is the usercontrol actually named frmBillingManagement, or is it named frmBillingManagement1... Me thinks you are using the constructor name not the actual instance.

Comment: i also changed that to frmBillingManagement1, but still the same.